# Hide with css all elements that doesn't contains {selector}

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have [example (js-fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/f7JgP/1/)
I want hide all tbody elements, that doesn't contains elements tr elements without class "day_label" and "hide"
In this exmaple i have stats for day, and i need to hide all day if there is no any record for day.

Comment: Hide a `tbody` that contains no `tr` with the class `day_label`?

Comment: In your example, which rows do you want hidden?

Comment: In example I need to hide tbody for "Yesterday" and "23 September"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is basically a CSS parent selector (`tr.hide < tbody { display: none; }​`), this doesn't exist yet. (soon!) However, this can be done quite easily with a library like jQuery:

```
$("tbody").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children("tr:not(.hide):not(.day_label)").length) { //Not 0
        $(this).addClass("show");
    }
});​
```

CSS:

```
tbody { display: none; }
tbody.show { display: block; }​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/RqBCY/

Answer (score 2):

To effectively select a parent based on it's children - what you are asking - is not possible with CSS *(at this particular frozen moment in time)*.

You have <del>two</del> three ;) options:

1. When generating your HTML (either with a server side language or in JS) generate your parents with classes that describe the state of the children. This way you can target the parent directly.
2. Use JavaScript to target your parent and then calculate whether or not it has the right kind of children. If it does, then apply a className that adds the styles you require.
3. For other situations you can also do as Abe Petrillo states - which is to inverse your logic and only enable when a particular selector is found. However I believe this wont work for what you are trying to do as it involves more complcated 'conditional logic' than can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but you could hide all rows, and then show the rows that are relevant:

```
tbody tr { display:none; }
tbody tr.day_label { display: block; }
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  
In example I need to hide tbody for "Yesterday" and "23 September"

Comment: Like @pebbl has mentioned, what you're trying to do is not possible with just CSS, you may want to use javascript or change your html

Comment: +1 @AbePetrillo - never-the-less it is a sound answer with regards to many parent->child css problems.